# Read data from 134kHz tag from a smartphone

Tags: rfid

Is there a way to configure the NCF reader from a smartphone to read 134kHz tag or is a smartphone able to power up an external reader so it can read the frequency? I need to read from a passive chip (EM4305) from a distance ~7cm. Another option that I was thinking is if I can convert the 134kHz signal into a NFC signal which mean I no longer need to connect something to the phone.

Comment: Your edit doesn't rally change anything - no, you can't do it directly.  Yes, you could do it with something in between.  No, finding/selecting that something in between is still not on topic.

Answer (score 2):

No. NFC is a 13.56 MHz technology and fundamentally not compatible with lower frequency systems.  A typical phone simply has no hardware capable of interacting with a 134 KHz system.

Naturally a variety of bridging devices are possible and probably on the market, which in addition to having a suitable 134 KHz transceiver might interact with the phone by any of BLE, USB (in either role), WiFi, audio, even conceivably NFC... but questions seeking information on what is available to purchase are deemed "shopping questions", outside the mission of this site, and off topic.